# Unable to acces on some websites when connected to VPN IKEv2 server from linux

Tags: vpn, strongswan, ikev2

I have a VPN server hosted on Windows 2019 and configured on IKEv2,
Everything works very well from all clients, however on Linux clients I have one last point to adjust, so for clarification I use the following script positioned in the dispatcher to adjust the MTU and add the necessary routes (which was not necessary in the case where the connection is L2TP):

```
#!/bin/bash
  
set -xv

DEFAULT_MTU=1500
MTU=1400

INTERFACE=$(ip route | grep -v linkdown | awk '$1 == "default" {if (!min || $5 < min) {min=$5; iface=$5}} END {print iface}')

if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^nm-xfrm-.* ]] && [[ ! "$1" =~ tun.* ]]; then
    echo "$1 is not a vpn interface. Exit script"
    exit 0
fi

if [ ! -d /sys/class/net/tun0 ]; then
    for itf in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -E -v '^(lo|ppp0)$' ); do
        sudo ip link set dev "$itf" mtu "$DEFAULT_MTU"
    done
fi

case "$2" in
up|vpn-up)
    ip link set dev "$INTERFACE" mtu "$MTU"
    ip link set dev $1 mtu "$MTU"
    ip route add to default dev $1 proto static scope link metric 50
    ip route add to XX.XX.XX.XX/XX dev $1 proto static scope link metric 50 table 220
    ;;

down|vpn-down)
    for itf in $(ls /sys/class/net/ | grep -E -v '^(lo|ppp0)$' ); do
        ip link set dev "$itf" mtu "$DEFAULT_MTU"
    done
    ;;
    *)
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

I use routing table 220 for docker machine.

And it turns out that if I connect via wifi everything works fine, access to websites via browser and via curl goes well, however as soon as I connect an USB-C adapter with an ethernet port some sites no longer respond.

I thought it was an MTU problem initially, but I'm wondering if there isn't something else causing the problem, or maybe it's not possible.

I specify that I use the strongswan package with NetworkManager.